# Unable to connect to mysqli database through php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a website where it has just had its php updated so now the custom plugin wont connect to the database. Originally I was getting an error saying the mysql() function was not defined so I changed it to mysqli() now that error has gone but I still cannot connect. I have checked and I have mysqli activated.

heres my code:

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); 

if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

if (! mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME)) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

All I keep getting is 'Can't use db:'. I have also tried defining the DB_HOST ect and that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: is your DB_NAME defined?

Comment: Try tu put the db_name inside the mysqli_connect function mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db")

Comment: `mysqli_error()` needs the database link to report the error - which if the connection fails is not going to happen - use `mysqli_connect_error()` instead.  (Note that all calls to `mysqli_error()` will need to be updated with the connection)

Comment: what's output of `echo DB_NAME;`

Comment: @matiit Thanks but I have already tried putting DB_NAME inside the function I still got the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_select_db` expects the first argument to be a MySQL link, try the following:

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); 

if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

if (! mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME)) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

For the future, I would recommend you to read about error reporting in PHP, it will help you to spot such mistakes much quicker.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

if you use mysqli_error() you would have to give the latest function with it.

in you case mysqli_error($link)